# Code Coverage Sonar Qube for my React Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gradle, sonarqube

The following is what I have for Coverage for my React JavaScript application.  I am getting coverage locally with running `npm test`, but not reported in SonarQube.  Can someone help me with what I am missing?

**Gradle**

```
// gradle sonar plugin configuration
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.projectName", "${project_name}-${version}"
        property "sonar.projectKey", "${project_name}-$version}"
        property "sonar.sources", "src/main/java/com/company/app,src/main/webapapp/appName/src"
        property "sonar.exclusions", "src/main/webapp/appName/src/assests/**"
        // Where to find tests file, also src
        property "sonar.tests", "src/main/java/com/company/app,src/main/webapp/appName/src"
        // But we get specific here
        // We do not need to exclude it in sonar.sources because it is automatically taken care of
        property "sonar.test.inclusions", "src/**/*.spec.js,src/**/*.spec.jsx,src/**/*.test.js,src**/*.test.jsx"
        // Now specify path of lcov and test log
        property "sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths", "src/main/webapp/appName/coverage/lcov.info"
        //property "sonar.testExecutionReportPaths", "src/main/webapp/appName/coverage-final.json // does not work
```

**sonar-project.properties**

```
# Source
sonar.sources=src

# Where to find tests file, also src
sonar.tests=src
# But we get specific here
# We do not need to exclude it in sonar.sources because it is automatically taken care of  
 sonar.test.inclusions=src/**/*.spec.js,src/**/*.spec.jsx,src/**/*.test.js
 ,src/**/*.test.jsx
 #sonar.testExecutionReportPaths=coverage/jest/testlog.xml
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest --coverage",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "jest": {
     "transform":{
         "^.+\\.[t|j]sx?$": "babel-jest"
      },
      "collectCoverage": true,
      "testResultsProcessor":"jest-sonar-reporter"
      },
      "homepage": "./",
      "devDependencies": {
        "jest": "^24.9.0",
        "jest-junit-reporter: "^1.1.0"
 },
 ...... removed for brevity
```

Answer (score 0):

The `jest-sonar-reporter` package is old and hasn't been updated in 4 years. It has issues with paths not working as intended and failing to be reported.

I have updated the plugin and republished it under `@casualbot/jest-sonar-reporter` to fix this functionality as well as add other features for the community.

Ex:

```json
package.json

{
  ...,
  "jest": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "testResultsProcessor": "@casualbot/jest-sonar-reporter"
  },
  "@casualbot/jest-sonar-reporter": {
    "suiteName": "jest tests",
    "outputDirectory": "coverage",
    "outputName": "jest-report.xml",
    "uniqueOutputName": "false",
    "classNameTemplate": "{classname}-{title}",
    "titleTemplate": "{classname}-{title}",
    "ancestorSeparator": " › ",
    "usePathForSuiteName": "true",
    "relativePaths": "true"
  }
}
```

Disclosure: I am the developer of the plugin.